# Find path of specific length between point A and B on grid

Tags: unity-game-engine, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a game that will always be an n x n grid. I'd like to be able to always generate a new start position from the outer edge and have a path to the center cell. My issue is that I want to be able to specify the path length instead of choosing the shortest path. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

I've looked at several CompSci forums, but unfortunately I'm unable to make heads or tails of what they're saying.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44401/what-algorithm-to-use-to-generate-random-path-of-given-length

[image]

Comment: What's your goal with this? There can be (kinda) easy solutions in many instances. E.g. random labyrinth with guaranteed solution

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the hardcore math, I would suggest to always use the shortest possible path and randomly generate and add some pieces to it to make it the length you want. It would not be absolute random, but for sure it should look good enough. Although it depends on your needs.